# JS Как сделать, чтобы эта функция срабатывала при checked вместо клика?

Tags: javascript, click

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.myDiv").hide();
        $("#show"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы эта функция срабатывала при checked вместо клика?

Comment: можно попробовать `change`

Answer (score 0):

По `change` наверное Вы хотели

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id=1 name="group1">
<input type="radio" id=2 name="group1">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
        console.log(this.id)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Я поставил checked одному из radio-input'ов, и надеялся что скрипт, который привязан к выбранному input'у (с атрибутом checked), будет сразу же выполняться, но этого не происходит, нужно все равно жать руками

Comment: @CoffeeinTime как Вы поставили `checked`, в разметке? если да, то тогда при *инициализации* проверяйте состояние нужного вам элемента и в соответствии с этим запускайте нужный обработчик

Answer (score 0):

Вот на чистом JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
 let radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

 for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) 
   radios[i].onchange = (event) => console.log(event.target);

}
```